# How to add 2 organs in 1 argument in list

Tags: python-3.x

I want start with empty list:

```
myList = []
```

and with some operation to create a list with 2 organs for 1 arguments, something like that:

```
myList = [['a',10],['b', 4],['g',142]]
```

I tried to do:

```
myList.append("[" + string + "," + str(number) + "]")
```

but when i do it, all of it saved as string and it save the value like this(with ""):

```
myList[0] = "['a',5]"
```

I like it to be:

```
myList[0] = ['a',5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
myList.append(['a',5])
```

You're creating a string version of your input (`+` on two strings just combines the strings into one string) but you just need to append the term you want, not create a string of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
myList.append([string,number])
```

Comment: Very short and precise, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Please up vote and accept the answer if you found it helpful. thanks.